# Why does loading a class that contains a Value-Type field enforces the CLR to load that value type?

Tags: c#, .net, clr, .net-assembly, value-type

Suppose I have the following types in the following assemblies:

Assembly1:

```
public struct DependencyStruct { }
public class DependencyClass { }
```

Assembly2:

```
public class UsingDependency
{
    private DependencyStruct m_DependencyStruct; // having this will field will cause the loading of the DependencyStruct type (thus will cause an assembly binding request).
    private DependencyClass m_DependencyClass; // having this field will **not** cause the loading of the DependencyClass type.
}
```

Assembly3 (Executable)

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("Assembly2.dll");
       Type[] types = assembly.GetTypes();
       Assembly[] assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
    }
}
```

When I run the following code, I will find Assembly2 and Assembly1 in the assemblies array.

If I comment out the m_DependencyStruct declaration, I will find only Assembly2 in the assemblies array.

Note that I'm not creating any instances in this code, just loading the types.

My questions are:

1. Why does having a value type field cause the CLR to load the entire type (as opposed to a reference type which has a deferred loading)?
2. Is there a way to defer that value-type loading? Using `Lazy<DependencyStruct> m_LazyDependencyStruct` or creating another wrapper class will work, but I'm curious if there's another way of doing this without changing the actual type.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is pretty hard to nail down, the code in the CLR that loads types is a complicated mass of C++ code.  One thing I see being done in the MethodTableBuilder::InitializeFieldDescs() method is that it also calculates the offsets of the fields in the class.

Which requires knowing how much storage is required for each field.  That's of course simple for fields of a reference type, it is just the size of a pointer.  But not for fields of a value type, it requires loading the type of the field, recursing as necessary through its fields to calculate their size.  Which of course has the side effect that you see the assembly that contains the value type loaded as well.

Just an educated guess.  You can have a look-see at the class.cpp source code file in the SSCLI20 distribution to look for yourself.  A strong implementation detail, make sure you never care about this.

Comment: Thanks
found it at MethodTable::DoFullyLoad
it states  
`// Fully load the exact field types for value type fields`

Answer (score 1):

This happens because the declaration of the struct variable causes the struct to be allocated, since a struct can't be null so the variable is to a default version of the struct.

The declaration of the class variable can be null, so doesn't need to allocate an occurrence of the class.

Comment: He just loads the Type, nothing is getting allocated.

Answer (score 0):

As the default value of the class(reference type) is `null` it doesn't need to load the type to set its default value whereas in `struct` being the value type it should be initialized to `new StructType` which is its default value, hence you see this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

In order to create an instance of a type that includes value-type fields, the CLR needs to know how much space to allocate inside the class's data section. The whole purpose of value types is that they are passed around "by value" - the entire type is present and accessed directly. This means the default value for that field requires initializing each member to *its* default value, etc. Doing so that requires loading all the metadata for that type.

A reference type, on the other hand, is passed around "by reference" - the only thing your container class needs to know is the size of a reference, which is the same for all reference types. The CLR doesn't need to know anything more about the reference type until you actually try to use it. The default value for a reference type doesn't "use" anything specific to the type, so there's no need to load the metadata until later.